# How to debug Dart code using the Flutter SDK on a terminal?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  var values = List<String>.filled(3, 0);

  values[0] = 'abc';
  values[1] = 'def';
  values[2] = 'ghi';
}
```

I am trying to have a regular debugging experience with breakpoints on my code. However, I don't want to design a UI screen on my emulator just to run a code that does not require UI presentation.

In other words, I am trying to run dart code in isolation from UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using VScode you can open a full new dart project with the ability to debug and test your code with:

1- click on `ctrl+shift+p` from your keyboard

2- search for `Dart: new project`, and click it

3- choose `console application`

4- choose a location for the dart project

5- that's it, now you can open the project folder from VScode and play in the `main.dart` with your code, and debug it.

Using other editors, you can do the same just from the terminal running this in the command line:

```
dart create nameOfProject
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the code is trying to access an element in the list that does not exist. The list only has 3 elements, so trying to access the 4th element (values[3]) will cause an error.

To fix this, you can either remove the line that tries to access values[3], or you can add another element to the list.

Answer (score 0):

if    `dart --version` works.

then you can do  `dart filename.dart`

don't forget to print

Comment: Fine, but how can I have a full debugging experience with the ability to apply breakpoints? I am using Visual Studio Code as my code editor and debugging practices.

Comment: you can't debug breakpoint on the terminal. But you could use the vscode debug console